# Angular: trying to get nested observable to work

Tags: angular, observable

For the life of me I can't get my head around nested observables.  I think I may need to go back to the training videos to get a deeper understanding than I have now. I understand all of the basic concepts but putting them all together is proving to be difficult.

For now I am trying to get this specific app to work.  I have a working example where I am making a call to an api and getting back an array that I have tied to an interface.  For each member of this array I need to do a lookup to another api using a value from the interface.  I will receive a single value back from that second api that I want to store in the interface.

I mocked up an example of what I am trying to do on stackblitz.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/call-http-request-in-angular-6-kyq1an?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: First of all you should take a look at what interface actually means. You can't store anything in an interface. Secondly, why looping through "httpData" and making a request each time doesn't work for you ?

Comment: Yes, I used "interface" incorrectly in my description.  I meant each element of the array.  I am new to angular and trying to piece all of this together.  I learn better by making things but I ran into a wall with this one.  Any help that you could provide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { concatMap, switchMap, take, toArray, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
  public httpData: IPostWithComments[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get(this.url)
    .pipe(
      // Reveiced an array of posts
      // Use "from" emit each value one by one
      switchMap((posts: IPost[]) => from(posts)),
      // Take(10) to avoid too many requests
      take(10),
      // For each post, fetch comments associated
      concatMap((post: IPost) => this.http.get(`${this.url}/${post.id}/comments`)
        .pipe(
          // Only take the first five comments
          map((comments: IComment[]) => comments.splice(0, 5))
        ),
        // Use result selector function to add comments in the post object
        (post: IPost, comments: IComment[]) => {
          const postWithComments: IPostWithComments = {...post, comments};
          return postWithComments;
        }
      ),
      // Aggregate all the posts in an array
      toArray()
    )
    .subscribe((postsWithComments: IPostWithComments[]) => {
      console.log(postsWithComments);
      this.httpData = postsWithComments;
    })

  }
}

interface Kafein {
  name:string;
  address:string;
}

interface IPost {
  completed: boolean;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  userId: number;
}

interface IPostWithComments extends IPost {
  comments: IComment[]
}

interface IComment {
  body: string;
  email: string;
  id: number;
  name: string;
  postId: number;
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/call-http-request-in-angular-6-pzhe5c?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the reply. Can you explain more about what this lines does?  Does it put the result into comments?

concatMap((post: IPost) => this.http.get(`${this.url}/${post.id}/comments`

Once I get that return how do I get the value back in to the original array?

Comment: Line 26,  request the comments for a post thanks to the post in concatMap argument and return an array of comments.
Line 29, get the array of comments (from line 26), extract only elements and return an array of 5 comments.
Line 32, it is the result selector function ([concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap)) that allow us to use outerValue (post from concatMap) and innerValue (the array of 5 comments), with this function we can assign comments to the post.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you thank you!  I was biting off a little more than I could chew.  I instead got a single page to work and then slowly the concepts started to become clear to me.  Really, thank you so much.